# Exception raised within Task.Factory.StartNew() does not get propagated to the caller

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following code in a Winforms application:

```
protected override async void Btn_Start_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await _crypto.DecryptStreamAsync(key, _io.FSIn, _io.FSOut, _tokenSource.Token);
        }, _tokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);

        //Some other UI related methods as well
    }
    catch (KeyException)
    {
        //Handle exception.
    }
    // Catch and handle other specific exceptions.
}
```

And the `DecryptStreamAsync` method:

```
public async Task DecryptStreamAsync(byte[] key, FileStream fsIn, FileStream fsOut, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[SaltSize];
    byte[] iv = new byte[IVSize];
    byte[] tag = new byte[TagSize];

    fsIn.Position = 0;
    await fsIn.ReadAsync(salt, 0, SaltSize, cancellationToken);
    await fsIn.ReadAsync(iv, 0, IVSize, cancellationToken);
    await fsIn.ReadAsync(tag, 0, TagSize, cancellationToken);

    var pbkdf2Key = GenerateKey(key, salt);
    var keyMaterial = new KeyMaterial(pbkdf2Key);
    if (!CompareByteArrays(tag, keyMaterial.VerificationTag)) // Compares the tag embedded with the encrypted file against the tag generated using the given key.
    {
        throw new KeyException("Incorrect key.");
    }

    _aesAlg.Key = keyMaterial.Key;
    _aesAlg.IV = iv;
    _aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = _aesAlg.CreateDecryptor();
    using CryptoStream cs = new(fsOut, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    await fsIn.CopyToAsync(cs, cancellationToken);      

    await cs.FlushFinalBlockAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

When I entered an incorrect key, the `KeyException` is thrown within the `DecryptStreamAsync` method as expected, and it is propagated to the caller that awaits the method (the anonymous function within the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method. But in this code, the exception is never propagated to the `Task.Factory.StartNew`'s caller (`Btn_Start_OnClick` method). So, the try-catch blocks I have placed do not catch any exception thrown within the `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

I have never encountered this kind of behavior when awaiting methods that throw exceptions (Mostly, in ASP.NET Core). But why does this happen when I use this `Task.Factory.StartNew`?

Comment: Why are you using `LongRunning` anyway? That only makes sense if your task is purely synchronous and heavily CPU bound, but this code appears to do a lot of IO

Comment: ​@Charlieface the `LongRunning` makes also sense for blocking I/O. But for asynchronous I/O, yea, it doesn't.

Comment: @Charlieface isn't an encryption process a combination of both IO and CPU bound work. Also, as per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=net-7.0) LongRunning is a hint to the task scheduler that the Task need a new thread instead of using thread pool threads?

Comment: Yes correct I'm just not convinced it needs it here, because decryption isn't usually that demanding, the IO is likely to be the overriding factor here. Needs testing definitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew) with `async` delegate returns a `Task<Task>`, not a simple non-generic `Task`. You have to `await` both the outer and inner task in order to observe both synchronous and asynchronous exceptions. Your options are:

1. Add a second `await`: `await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async`.
2. Use the [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap): `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current).Unwrap();`
3. Ditch the primitive `Task.Factory.StartNew`, and use the simpler and smarter `Task.Run` instead. The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) understands async delegates, and observes both synchronous and asynchronous exceptions automatically.

My advice is to follow the 3rd option. If you want to learn more, I suggest reading this article: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).