# ConfigureAwait(false) in long running task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, configureawait

I May have a misconception about something.
For me in an async method, having ConfigureAwait(false); will permit the task to continue being executed on the threadpool.

So if I Declare a LongRunning Task on a dedicated thread, for a background work (like checking some work on a queue)

```
   _managementTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
   {
    while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
       await Task.Delay(10000, _cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
       await CheckWork().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
   }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Then it means that because of the first ConfigureAwait(false), all the following code and loops will be excuted on the threadpool instead of on a the dedicated thread created by the "LongRunning" Task Creation, so It would be the same as executing a task on the threadpool from the very start.

Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: ​As a side note, unless the type of `_managementTask` is `Task<Task>` you are doing something wrong. For an explanation see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77030162/exception-raised-within-task-factory-startnew-does-not-get-propagated-to-the-c "Exception raised within Task.Factory.StartNew() does not get propagated to the caller").

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, which is why `LongRunning` is almost always useless with an `async` delegate.

Furthermore, if there's no current task scheduler (and there usually isn't one), then the same is true for any `await`, with or without `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

As a side note, `LongRunning` is just a hint to the thread pool. It doesn't guarantee a dedicated thread.

As a general rule, use `Task.Run` to schedule asynchronous work to the thread pool, not `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the task scheduler aspect?

Comment: What can i do if i want a dedicated thread for performance purpose? Like a very high priority task

Comment: @Duagt just don't use `async`. Check out this question: [LongRunning Task behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77121950/longrunning-task-behaviour).

Comment: @Duagt: I have a [blog post with more detail](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html): `StartNew` will use the current task scheduler by default. Usually there isn't one, and in that case `StartNew` will run the delegate on the thread pool. `Task.Run` always runs its delegate on the thread pool. If the code is on the thread pool  there's no [context captured by `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and therefore `ConfigureAwait(false)` is the same as `ConfigureAwait(true)`.

Comment: `What can i do if i want a dedicated thread for performance purpose? Like a very high priority task` Avoid premature optimization. First write the code naturally. Then measure in real-world scenarios. If the performance is unacceptable, *then* consider complicating it.

Comment: I ask because it is the case.

Comment: You mean `Task.Run` is not performant enough, **and** you have determined that a dedicated thread would solve the problem?

Comment: Stephen Cleary I guess the OP has a saturated thread pool.

Comment: Yes in case of a huge workload on the threadpool, that is saturated, but one of my task, a very long running background task, has a higher priority and shouldnt be impacted by this workload and should be executed without interruptions..

Comment: Also In term of performance : 
Even if the result is the same in .net Core, as the task will endup on the threadpool in the absence of a custom synchronization context, 
Isnt it better to call ConfigureAwait(false) aniway, as it prevent from doing unecessary operations of trying to capture the context ?  (I understand the performance cost is negligible, but lets say we are in a very high performance context where each microsecond is important,  it is just to understand).

Comment: @Duagt have you considered configuring the thread pool with the [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) method, to reduce the likelihood of saturation? Or maybe investigate the culprit of the saturation? The `Parallel.ForEach` is one of the [usual suspects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418588/parallel-foreach-on-a-blockingcollection-causes-steady-increase-of-threads).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It doesn't really matter, because even if I add more thread, they will eventually be used to process my workload, and that will lead to the same problem.
And the more thread there is, the less my priority task will be scheduled to run as it will increase concurrency.

Comment: @Duagt ideally you would want to find a solution to the saturation problem. Having a saturated thread pool is asking for trouble. Since you have given up on that, a dedicated thread is the next decent option. Just make sure that you don't combine `LongRunning` and `async`. The `action` must be synchronous. Replace all `await` with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to stay on the dedicated thread. The `Task.Delay` completes on the `ThreadPool`, so replace it with `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Btw,  About the LongRunning hint,  does it actually create a dedicated thread outside the threadpool ? 

Or just dispatch the task on the threadpool, while also creating one more thread on the threadpool without waiting the 0.5sec usually necessary to scale it up ?

Comment: It's currently implemented as an additional thread pool thread that skips the normal scale throttling. When the delegate completes, I'm not sure if the thread is released to the thread pool or allowed to terminate. I *suspect* the former but I've never checked.

Comment: @Duagt check out the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/782c9d340dd2b69600049adbac714366a1634547/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs#L42) of the internal class `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, which is the `TaskScheduler.Default`. I you want to be 100% sure that a dedicated thread will be created for the task, you can pass a custom `TaskScheduler` as argument to the `Task.Factory.StartNew`, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570579/is-it-possible-always-to-force-a-new-thread-with-task/68929857#68929857).